# conditional check in java 8 stream apis

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have below existing implementation

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails =
            empIds.stream().map(empId ->
                employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId)))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

In this code I need to check in HashMap that empId is already present or not as below - if empId is not present in HashMap then call service and put it into HashMap for future purpose.

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<Employee>[]> employeeCache = new HashMap<>();

..........

CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails =
            empIds.stream().map(empId ->

            //Here I need to check in HashMap that empId is present or not if present then fetch from Map instead of calling service.

                employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId)))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

How I can add `if` check in `stream()` api as shown in above and if present then get from Map.

Comment: Do you need the map further, i.e. later in the code, for something else? Or do you only need it within the `Stream.map` function, to use it as a cache?

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<Employee>[]> employeeCache = new HashMap<>();

CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails = empIds.stream()
                .map(empId -> employeeCache
                        .computeIfAbsent(empId, k -> employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))))
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks Minar. I forget to mention that if key is not present HashMap then fetch from service and put it into hashmap. How I can Put value into HashMap in this case. Here default value is always call to service but I need to put that value in HashMap also after service call.

Comment: @ppb I have updated the answer. Please see if it helps.

Comment: So here computeIfAbsent() will put value in map if not present?

Comment: According to the documentation, the [mapper function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) supplied to `map` should be non-interfering and stateless.

Comment: Thanks Minar. I am trying to right Junit for this but not sure how I can mock employeeCache map and assertEqual or assertThat for the map.

Comment: The function passed to `computeIfAbsent` receives the key as parameter, so you can use `k` instead of capturing `empId` here. The `Integer.valueOf` also seems redundant, so you could even use `empId -> employeeCache .computeIfAbsent(empId, employeeService::employeeDetails) …` here. Besides that, I recommend fixing the misleading indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T))(since lack of key in a `Map` would return `null`) along with [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) (to make the service call when the value isn't present in the `Map`) in your `Stream.map` operation as:

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails = empIds.stream()
        .map(empId -> Optional.ofNullable(employeeCache.get(empId))
                .orElseGet(() -> employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

or as suggested by Aomine in comments, you could simply use `getOrDefault` as well:

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails = empIds.stream()
        .map(empId -> employeeCache.getOrDefault(empId, 
                employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

<strike>If you want to put in the cache as well, you could simply use [`Map.putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) to put if not present as:</strike>

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails = empIds.stream()
        .map(empId -> employeeCache.putIfAbsent(empiId, employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

If you want to update the cache as well while fecthing from the service, you're probably better of without streams here:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Employee>[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String empId : empIds) {
    CompletableFuture<Employee>[] completableFutures = employeeCache.putIfAbsent(employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId)));
    if (completableFutures != null) {
        list.add(completableFutures);
    }
}
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails = list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]);
```

---

Besides, all of that (if I were you) I would have used Guava's [`LoadingCache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) which provides similar benefits under the covers with even a custom `CacheLoader` implementation.

For further details over it you can read their wiki - [CachesExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: @ppb do you want to add it to the map as well while fetching from the service?

Comment: yes. I want to add it to the map as well while fetching from the service so in future I don't need to call service again for that empId.

Comment: @ppb updated. then use `putIfAbsent`, it would return the value if already present, or else put it in the map and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't further need the `employeeCache` map, i.e. if you are only using it as a local cache within the `Stream.map` operation, you could abstract it away via a generic utility method:

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, U> memoize(Function<T, U> f) {
    Map<T, U> m = new HashMap<>();
    return t -> m.computeIfAbsent(t, f);
}
```

This is called [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and is a well-known technique, especially in functional programming.

Then, you'd use it in your example as follows:

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails = empIds
    .stream()
    .map(memoize(empId -> employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

As you see, this is totally transparent to the caller code and it will indeed use the map as a cache.

**EDIT:** Please note that I've used just a common `HashMap`, because I've noticed the stream was run sequentially. If you are to ever run the stream in parallel, you should change the cache to `ConcurrentHashMap`.